# How to write a regex pattern to match string with currency sybol at end OR start of string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex pattern in Python that will only match the substrings which have a currency symbol/word attached.

**String example:**

```
'50,000 and £200.6m, 50p, 500m euro, 800bn euros, $15bn and $99.99. The year 2006 is 20% larger.'
```

**Expected matches:**

1. £200.6m
2. 50p
3. 500m euro
4. 800bn euros
5. $15bn
6. $99.99

I do not want numbers that are not currency related to match, such as plain numbers, percentages or years.

**My attempt:**

```
(^(£|\$)?)\d+([.,]\d*)?|(\d+([.,]\d*)?(p|(bn|m)|(\seuro(s)))$)
```

**My matches:**

1. 50,000

Evidently the regex isn't working at all as I expect. It should either match a substring if it begins with a currency symbol or if it ends with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a pattern to match either the euro or dollar sign `[£$]`, the value optionally followed by `p` `m` or `bn`.

Or match the value followed by `p` `m` or `bn` and euro with optional s

```
(?:[£$]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[pm]|bn)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[pm]|bn)(?: euros?)?)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[£$]` A character class matching either `£` or `$`
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `(?:[pm]|bn)?` Optionally match either `p` or `m` or `bn`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with optional decimal part
  - `(?:[pm]|bn)` Match either `p` or `m` or `bn`
  - `(?: euros?)?` Optionally match a space and `euro` with optional `s`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fua5Wl/1)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do it:

```
(?:£|\$)(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:m|bn)?|(?:\d*\.)?\d+(?:m|bn)? ?(?:p|euros?)
```

Just keep adding the currencies you wish to catch to the respective `(?:£|\$)` or `(?:p|euros?)` sections. Ditto for adding items to `(?:m|bn)`

https://regex101.com/r/3K9jmR/1